# jQuery dropdown box always shows first item

Tags: jquery, sql, xml, html-select, selectedindex

In a jQuery function I am working with, I use a .get to return some XML data & then use it to populate a drop down box.  The code that I use to build the `<OPTION>` tags in the select follows:

```
$.get(sURL, function(data) {
    var select = $("#dList");
    $(data).find("Row").each(function() {
    var mgid = $(this).find("MessageGroupID").text();
    var gname = $(this).find("GroupName").text();
    var option = $("<option>" + gname + "</option>");
    option.attr("value", mgid);
    select.append(option);
    });
});
```

The XML that is being parsed is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rowsets DateCreated="2013-05-07T11:33:51" EndDate="2013-05-07T11:33:51" StartDate="2013-05-07T10:33:51" Version="1.1.1">
<Rowset>
<Columns>
<Column Description="MessageGroupID" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="MessageGroupID" SQLDataType="4" SourceColumn="MessageGroupID"/>
<Column Description="GroupName" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="GroupName" SQLDataType="12" SourceColumn="GroupName"/>
</Columns>
<Row>
<MessageGroupID>1</MessageGroupID>
<GroupName>First Shift</GroupName>
</Row>
<Row>
<MessageGroupID>4</MessageGroupID>
<GroupName>Alternate First Shift</GroupName>
</Row>
<Row><MessageGroupID>7</MessageGroupID>
<GroupName>Temporary First Shift</GroupName>
</Row>
</Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

I call the function to load the drop down in the document.ready part of the script.

When the 3 rows are returned, the first row is always showing in the drop down box.  Or, if I prepend a blank line:

```
var blankline = $("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");
```

I get the blank drop down box, but now have 4 items in the drop down (a blank + the 3 I should have).  I thought that setting the selectedindex= -1 would do it, but it has no effect since these items aren't static.

How do you get the drop down box to have both a blank/empty display value, and still have the appropriate number of items in the actual option list?

Thanks!

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').click(function(){
        $(this).children(':eq("0")').hide();
        $(this).unbind('click');
    });
}); // untested Code
```

**EDIT:**

PLease try this...

```
$('select').one('mousedown',function(){
    $("option:first",this).remove();
});
```

I was myself confused in this.. Finally [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426027/why-the-jquery-remove-is-adding-an-extra-element-in-the-dropdown#16426128) this on SO and finally got a beautiful answer..

Comment: This seems to work okay in Firefox, but in IE it doesn't.  Google Chrome does something a little different - it hides the empty row in the dropdown, but it doesn't reshuffle the list.  The last item is repeated unless the drop down is clicked a second time, but it's not selectable.  Nothing is throwing an error that I see.  Any idea why its behaving this way?

Comment: Thank you.  It seems to be behaving similarly in all 3 browsers now.  On the dropdown though, when it's clicked, the box is automatically populated with the first entry, which is almost back to where the initial question came from.  Reading thru your post now also.