# Why the jQuery remove is adding an extra element in the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/writetobhuwan/Cbyvj/)..

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option>hey1</option>
    <option>hey2</option>
    <option>hey3</option>
    <option>hey4</option>
    <option>hey5</option>    
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').on('click',function(){
        $("option:first",this).remove();
        $(this).unbind('click');
    });
});
```

When I run the above code in google Chrome(latest version), the first element is removed but it appends an extra element at the bottom. Why is it behaving like that.

Any ideas? pretty unexpected ..

**EDIT:**

This picture is for the ones who are not able to see any error..

[image: Strange Behaviour]

Comment: What is the goal you are trying to achieve...remove the selected item on change?

Comment: No, remove the first element on clicking the select..

Comment: and unbind that event after it has been executed once..

Comment: Are you trying to put words in the select for users to read??

Comment: I don't see that it's appending any extra item

Comment: No, nothing like that.. I just want to remove/hide the first element. Thats all..

Comment: @hunter open that fiddle in chrome..

Comment: @writeToBhuwan - That seems to be exactly what it's doing

Comment: This just looks like a visual bug to me .. you can't actually select the other option

Comment: Yeah looks like a rendering bug since you can't pick the last hey5. Plus the DOM is correct.

Comment: The moment you click the select element it removes the first `option` = "hey1" and then unbinds the click, leaving "hey2", "hey3", "hey4", and "hey5"

Comment: @j08691 How should I solve that?

Comment: It works just fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/WvDx5/1/ Version 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: I don't see the problem in Version 27.0.1453.73 beta. In fact, the `click` handler doesn't run at all.

Comment: what is your first **Extension** in chrome?:)

Comment: @mdvlpr are you talking about this? http://i.imgur.com/IDxYmzI.png

Comment: So whats your verdict after seeing my extenstions? Is this causing any problem in rendering? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a rendering bug in Chrome. You can't actually click on the last hey5 and the DOM doesn't actually create a second one. You can get around this via mousedown:

```
$('select').one('mousedown',function(){
    $("option:first",this).remove();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Cbyvj/7/)**

Comment: I also changed the `.on()`/`.unbind()` to `.one()`. Saves a little code.

Comment: beautiful code.. This is forcing me to accept your solution as answer.. (huh, this time limit in SO)

Comment: yep, using `one` is better :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug, another fix is using `focus` event :

```
$('select').on('focus', function(){
    $("option:first", this).remove();
    $(this).unbind('focus');
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F8E7L/